# Enum in debugging doesn't have a value after step

Tags: c

I have a enum: enum Result `{OK,ERROR};`  - for example. 
and I have a function:

```
enum Result ReturnAEnumValue() {
}
```

- f.e
  which return OK or ERROR.

And in `main(){}` I create a enum type:

```
enum Result eResult; 
eResult = Result();
```

Why in my debugger after stepping i don't have any value in eResult? 
If I earlier give a eResult a value for example:
enum Result eResult = ERROR; it works.

```
enum Result {OK,ERROR}; 
enum Result eHexStringToUInt(char pcStr[], unsigned int *puiValue) { 
    unsigned char ucCharCounter;
    if ((pcStr[0] != '0' )||( pcStr[1] != 'x')||( pcStr[2]== '\0' ) || (pcStr[6] != '\0')){
        return ERROR;
    }
    *puiValue = 0;
    for (ucCharCounter = 2; ucCharCounter< 6 ; ucCharCounter++) 
    {
        *puiValue = *puiValue << 4; 
        if (pcStr[ucCharCounter] < 'A')
        {
            *puiValue = *puiValue | (pcStr[ucCharCounter] - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            *puiValue = *puiValue | (pcStr[ucCharCounter] - 'A' + 10);
        }
    }
    return OK;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int uiValue = 65000;
    char cHexStr[12] = "0xF5A7";
    enum Result eReturnValue;   
    eReturnValue = eHexStringToUInt(cHexStr , &uiValue);
}
```

[A debuuger info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggl7I.png)

Comment: Probably because it has no side effect, it is optimized out by the compiler. Try printing it.

Comment: The check of your input is incomplete. Think about what happens if you try to convert "0x12"...

Answer (score 2):

As your code does not use this value any optimiszation level will force the compiler to optimize it out. So try to use your varaible somehow (for example printf ir);